# Add values to existing rows -DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm appending some weather data (from json- dict) - in Japanese to DataFrame.

I would like to have something like this

```
        天気             風
 0  状態: Clouds    風速: 2.1m
 1     NaN          向き: 230
```

But I have this

```
        天気             風
 0  状態: Clouds        NaN
 1      NaN          風速: 2.1m
 2      NaN           向き: 230
```

How Could I change the Codes to make it like that?
Here is the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['天気','風'])
df = df.append({'天気': weather_status}, ignore_index=True) # 状態: Clouds - value
df = df.append({'風': wind_speed}, ignore_index=True) # 風速: 2.1m -value
df = df.append({'風': wind_deg}, ignore_index=True) # 向き: 230 -value
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['天気','風'])
df = df.append({'天気': weather_status, '風': wind_speed}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'風': wind_deg}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

And print without index

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: Is there a way to lose that index numbers?